# Nesting an array of an array in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, loops, nested-loops

I started a new `React` Project.

I created Images that I imported in:

```
    import Tip1 from "./img/Tips1.png";
    import Tip2 from "./img/Tips2.png";
    import Tip22 from "./img/Tips2-2.png";
...
```

I put them into arrays:

```
const TIP1 = [{ img: Tip1 }];
const TIP2 = [{ img: Tip2 }, { img: Tip22 }, { img: Tip222 }, { img: Tip2222 }];
const TIP3 = [{ img: Tip3 }, { img: Tip31 }, { img: Tip32 }, { img: Tip33 }];
const TIP4 = [{ img: Tip4 }, { img: Tip42 }];
```

Created extra modal that pops up when we click on the images.

and I created a function that displays these arrays one by one by using `.map`:

```
    const Tips = () => {
      const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
      const [selectedImageData, setImageData] = useState({ img: "" });
    
      const onImageClicked = (imageData) => {
        setImageData(imageData);
        setIsOpen(true);
      };

     //Unique ID
      const getUID = () => {
        return Math.ceil((Math.random() * 10000))
      }
    
      return (
        <>
          <div className="mt-5 mb-3">
            <h2> TIP #1 </h2>{" "}
          </div>
    
          {TIP1.map((imageData) => {
            return (
              <div className="card tips--card mt-5 mb-5 me-5 ms-5 ms-auto me-auto" key={getUID()}>
                <img
                  src={imageData.img}
                  alt="Vocab1"
                  className="card-img-top tips--img"
                  onClick={() => onImageClicked(imageData)}
                />
                <div className="card-body"></div>
              </div>
            );
          })}
    
          <div className="row ms-auto me-auto">
            <div className="mt-5 mb-3">
              <h2> TIP #2 </h2>{" "}
            </div>
            {TIP2.map((imageData) => {
              return (
                <div className="card tips--card mt-5 mb-5 me-5 ms-5 ms-auto me-auto" key={getUID()}>
                  <img
                    src={imageData.img}
                    alt="Vocab1"
                    className="card-img-top tips--img"
                    onClick={() => onImageClicked(imageData)}
                  />
                  <div className="card-body"></div>
                </div>
              );
            })}

    ...
```

And in the end of the function I added the Modal:

```
...
      {isOpen && (
        //  bind the selected image data state to a data prop on Modal
        <Modal
          // data ={isOpen }
          image={selectedImageData.img}
          //  close the modal
          setIsOpen={setIsOpen}
        />
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

[The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSeGA.png)

It works, but it is not scalable at all, and looks goofy with this much code.

My plan is to create a nested loop by using an extra array:

```
const TIPS = [
  { TIP: TIP2 },
  { TIP: TIP3 },
  { TIP: TIP4 },
  { TIP: TIP5 },
  { TIP: TIP6 },
  { TIP: TIP7 },
  { TIP: TIP8 },
  { TIP: TIP9 },
];
```

And this is where I stuck.
My best shot was creating an other map so far but it didn't bring closer to the solution.

**My question:**
***How could I create a Nested loop that displays the images from the array of an array?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a syntactical mistake. Basically, I didn't realize I needed to refer to the previous `.map` in the second `.map` and I assumed it will see it automatically.

```
{TIPS.map((TIPDATA) => {
        return (
          <div class="container">
<div className="row mt-5">
<h2>STEP #{ counter ++ }</h2>
            {TIPDATA.TIP.map((imageData) => {
              return (
             
                <div className=" card tips--card mt-5 mb-5 me-5 ms-5 ms-auto me-auto" key={getUID()}>
        
             <img
            src={imageData.img}
            alt="Vocab1"
            className="card-img-top tips--img"
            onClick={() => onImageClicked(imageData)}
            key={getUID()}
          />
             </div>
      
              );
              
            }

          
            )
          }
          

</div>
</div>

   
      
        
        );
      })}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see what you want, you are already on the right track, all you need to do is to call the `map` twice.

```
  {TIP.map((TIPRow, i) => {
    // this is each row
    return (
      <div key={"row" + i}>
        {TIPRow.map(imageData => {
          // this is the image as in your code
        }}
      </div>
    )
  }}
```

As you said it's nested, you can replace `div` with any other html structure you want, ex. `tr`, or `li`. This is up to you at this point.

NOTE: the challenge is to work with each bracket, `[({`, so if it's first time, just write slowly, ex. only try to get the first loop working by printing out a row, and then work on second loop. Otherwise the level of bracket could cost you a day ;)

Comment: Maybe something like this?

{TIPS.map((TIP, i) => {
    
    return (
      <div className="card tips--card mt-5 mb-5 me-5 ms-5 ms-auto me-auto" key={getUID() + i}>
        {(TIP as unknown as string  as any).map((imageData: any) => {
          return (
            <img
            src={imageData.img}
            alt="Vocab1"
            className="card-img-top tips--img"
            onClick={() => onImageClicked(imageData)}
          />
          )
        }
        
        )

        }
        
         </div>

        
    )
  }
    
    )}

Comment: yeah, something like that, also if you are new to Javascript, just don't use Typescript, it'll only slow you down. I'm not against Typescript, my work is all with Typescript, but it does add quite a bit boiler stuff when you are trying to only learn something new, if you know what i mean.